# Embedding Google Forms on a web page and extract responses on submit inside a browser

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications, google-forms

I am new to Google Forms (or Google Sheets) as a tool that can be embedded in a web application.

I have been able to embed a survey form (created via Google Forms) and on submission can see that it is stored in the linked spreadsheet.

The user-case I am trying is:

(a) embed the form on a web page (say within an iframe).
(b) on submission, the javascript in the browser gets access to the responses of the user
(c) after which I make the normal call to my backend via the API

For step (b) I am unable to figure out how to proceed? All the documentation to the Google Apps Scripts seem to be how to embed scripts on a spreadsheet etc. I was wondering if there is some Javascript library that I can use, whose methods I could call from the front end browser to capture the filled fields on submit.

Comment: I think that in the current stage, I think that when Google form embedded in Web Apps is submitted, there is no library for directly retrieving the submitted values using Javascript on the Web Apps. For example, how about using the OnSubmit event trigger for Google Apps Script? Or, how about creating the custom form instead of Google form? But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: As @Tanaike has said what you look for is already implemented with apps script and the creation of an [`onFormSubmit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onformsubmit). You idea of implementation is very convoluted and hard to implement, with the need of a webapp.

Comment: Asking for external recommendations resources is off-topic on this site.